# Finding a better name for "context" or "variant" for describing a software object concept

Tags: word-usage, terminology, programming

**Problem:**

In a software product, there is the possibility to define sets of parameters
(key, value pairs). The functionality is encapsulated in an object in the
code, to be reused by programmers wherever the functionality is needed.

Those *parameter sets* objects must have a name.

There is a second level of naming: it is possible to define multiple "versions" of the parameter values, each set of values being also identified with a name.

So, the `EXPERIMENT` parameters set can have fields like:

- sample name
- date
- data directory

There would be `experiment 1` with some values, and `experiment 2` with
different values.

How would you call "experiment 1" and "experiment 2" ?

I came with *context*, could also be *variant* or similar...

Indeed one can display the value of `EXPERIMENT.contexts` and see `['experiment1, 'experiment 2']` and then it is possible to *switch to* or *activate* "experiment 1" or "experiment 2" to get updated parameters values
for the `EXPERIMENT` object.

(sorry for the long description but it is not an easy thing to describe !)

**Question:** would you help me finding better names for the contexts/variants ? And for the *parameters set* object ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about _instances_? experiment_1 and experiment_2 are both instances of EXPERIMENT. And EXPERIMENT is an _object_. Seems pretty straight-forward to me

Comment: instances is not bad, but it is connoted in object-oriented programming. In reality "experiment 1" and "experiment 2" are **not** instances of "EXPERIMENT" (in the OOP sense). EXPERIMENT is an instance of a class, but the other two are "views" (or similar... this is what I am searching for) of the parameters with different values

Comment: I know the notion is reserved in OOP, but from a more logical pov, this is still an _instance_. Other ideas: You could call EXPERIMENT a _concept_, and _experiment 1_ could be called _realization_, for instance.

Comment: Context, Environment, Configuration.   Not view though. A view is for looking at the ***same*** thing from different perspectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call them **setups**. From Merriam-Webster:

> **setup** *noun*
>
> 2
>
> - A : the assembly and arrangement of the tools and apparatus required for the performance of an operation
> - B : the preparation and adjustment of machines for an assigned task

The definition listed here might have physical machines in mind, but the analogy seems fairly transparent.

Answer (score 0):

In the FHIR system for medical data that would be a codeable concept.

http://hl7.org/fhir/DSTU2/datatypes.html#CodeableConcept for JSON or the java class in HL7 is org.hl7.fhir.instance.model.CodeableConcept;

You can see how it's used for in the Procedure resource for example where they are used to save procedure codes, the body site etc. 
http://hl7.org/fhir/DSTU2/procedure.html